# Interact between Model and ViewModel of different UserControls without violating MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

**EDIT: Added concrete example to clarify what I trying to achieve.**

Here is application scheme:

[image]

To make code simpler, I will use trivial **Messenger** class instead of event aggregator from Prism. Tuple contains Id and string payload.

```
public static class Messenger
{
    public static event EventHandler<Tuple<int, string>> DoWork;

    public static void RaiseDoWork(int id, string path)
    {
        DoWork?.Invoke(null, new Tuple<int, string>(id, path));
    }
}
```

**Model instance** subscribe to messenger for knowing when to start work (if Id correct), and notify view-model when work finished.

```
public class Model
{
    public int id;

    public Model(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;

        Messenger.DoWork += (sender, tuple) =>
        {
            if (tuple.Item1 != this.Id)
            {
                return;
            }

            var result = tuple.Item2 + " processed with id " + this.id;
            this.OnWorkCompleted(result);
        };
    }

    public event EventHandler<string> WorkCompleted;

    private void OnWorkCompleted(string path)
    {
        this.WorkCompleted?.Invoke(null, path);
    }
}
```

**`UserControlResult`** is responsible for payload processing and result output. To make code simpler, lets just trace output instead of putting it on UI. So XAML will be default.

Code-behind:

```
public partial class UserControlResult : UserControl
{    
    private ResultViewModel viewModel;

    public UserControlResult()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Init(int id)
    {
        this.viewModel = new ResultViewModel(id);
        this.DataContext = this.viewModel;
    }
}
```

View-model:

```
public class ResultViewModel
{
    private Model model;

    public ResultViewModel(int id)
    {
        this.model = new Model(id);

        this.model.WorkCompleted += path =>
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(path);
        };
    }
}
```

**`UserControlButtons`** contains buttons, one of them should start processing of model in `UserControlResult` via messenger. To make code simpler, lets omit command implementation and just show its handler.

Code-behind:

```
public partial class UserControlButtons : UserControl
{    
    private ButtonsViewModel viewModel;

    public UserControlButtons()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Init(int id)
    {
        this.viewModel = new ButtonsViewModel(id);
        this.DataContext = this.viewModel;
    }
}
```

View-model:

```
public class ButtonsViewModel
{
    private int id;

    public ButtonsViewModel(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // DelegateCommand implementation...

    private void StartWorkingCommandHandler()
    {
        Messenger.RaiseDoWork(this.id, "test path");
    }
}
```

**`UserControlParent`** contains both `UserControlResult` and `UserControlButtons`. His only role is to pass Id to them, so he doesn't even need view-model.

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <uc:UserControlResult x:Name="UserControlResult" />
    <uc:UserControlButtons x:Name="UserControlButtons" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class UserControlParent : UserControl
{    
    public UserControlParent()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Init(int id)
    {
        this.UserControlResult.Init(id);
        this.UserControlButtons.Init(id);
    }
}
```

And finally **`MainWindow`** contains two instances of `UserControlParent`. Its role to assign them different Ids.

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <uc:UserControlParent x:Name="UserControlParent1" />
    <uc:UserControlParent x:Name="UserControlParent2" />
</StackPanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.UserControlParent1.Init(111);
        this.UserControlParent2.Init(222);
    }
}
```

This will work: pressing button in `UserControlButtons` will start working in `UserControlResult` model, and both `UserControlParent` will working correct and independend thanks to Id.

But I believe that this chain of invoking `Init` methods is **violates MVVM** because code-behind (which is *View* in MVVM) should **not** know anything about Id value (which is relative to *Model* in MVVM). Talking that, I'm sure that Id is not part of view-model, because it doesn't have any presentation in UI.

How can I pass Id value from top window to "deepest" view-models without violating MVVM?

### **Original Question**

Here is WPF application consisting from 3 `UserControl`s:

[image]

`UserControl3` is a part of `UserControl2` content. I keep *MVVM* during developing and using *Prism*.

I need to invoke method of custom class (which is *model* in terms of MVVM) in `UserControl3` from *view-model* of `UserControl1`. The restriction that custom class can't be singleton. I suppose to do it one of the following way:

1. Using event aggregator from Prism. `UserControl1` view-model is publisher and `UserControl3` model is subscriber. For this I'll need to create unique Id in `Window` and pass it to `UserControl1` and `UserControl3`.
2. Creating service instance in `Window` and pass it to `UserControl1` and `UserControl3`. Then `UserControl1` will just invoke method of this instance.
3. `Window` pass `UserControl2` instance to `UserControl1`. View-model in `UserControl1` will just invoke method of `UserControl2`, which will invoke method of `UserControl3` and so on.

It seems like 2 and 3 approaches violates MVVM. How would you resolve this situation?

Comment: Sending a command or raising an event feels like the better way without tight coupling the classes together... the major difference between the two concepts is: commands are rather "live" or at the moment tasks while an event is something that happened in the _past_.

Comment: How is there a service method "*in*" a control? I propose that you put your service methods someplace else, and have a parent viewmodel pass that in to any viewmodel that needs them (or just make it a global singleton if you're not doing automated testing). Any solution to this problem that even acknowledges the existence of controls is wrong. Controls shouldn't know web services exist; they should just know about is the properties of their DataContexts.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I should clarify: by service I mean usual class instance that storing as variable in view-model of `UserControl3`, so it is _model_ part of MVVM for `UserControl3`. E.g. this class receives path of image, asynchronously load and process image, then return image to view-model of `UserControl3`. The problem is to correctly start this process from view-model of `UserControl1`.

Comment: @kayess I suggest you mean 1 option when talking about event... but how can I use command for messaging between view-models of _different_ UserControls? If I understood you correctly, of course.

Comment: @CloseVote How can I improve question, why it should be closed?

Comment: @Sam You keep talking about controls. Don't talk about controls, don't think about controls. I think that you think of your program as a collection of controls that have viewmodels inside them, and then you try to figure out how the viewmodels can communicate. That's not MVVM. In MVVM, your program is a collection of viewmodels, and then you have views that display them. Design the viewmodel relationships. I repeat: "Any solution to this problem that even acknowledges the existence of controls is wrong."

Comment: Without a more specific scenario, and a clear problem statement (i.e. "I tried this, but it didn't work because..."), this question is entirely opinion based. Please improve it by providing a good [mcve] that shows what you've tried, and a precise description of what that code does, what you want it to do instead, and why you aren't able to get it to do that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for clarification, later I will add update to question with particular example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I achieved truly MVVM implementation shown in simplified example below. Special thanks to Ed Plunkett's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273603/invoke-model-logic-in-one-usercontrol-from-view-model-in-another-usercontrol-wit#comment65887070_39273603) and Nikita's [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/140542/110275).

First, I don't need to pass unique Ids anymore. For identification of different `ParentViewModel` instances, I just pass them different `Messenger` instances (which replaces *Prism's EventAggregator* for the sake of simplicity):

```
internal class Messenger
{
    public event EventHandler<string> DoWork;

    public void RaiseDoWork(string path)
    {
        this.DoWork?.Invoke(this, path);
    }
}
```

Second, it seems like in my particular case Model should not worry about `Messenger`'s `DoWork` event. As soon as this event raised in one view-model (`ButtonsViewModel`), it is more appropriate for this event to be consumed by another view-model (`ResultViewModel`) rather than by `Model` itself. So `Model` simplified too:

```
internal class Model
{
    public string Process(string input)
    {
        return input + " processed!";
    }
}
```

Below demonstrated all view-models "from top to bottom".

```
internal class MainViewModel
{
    private readonly Messenger eventAggregator1 = new Messenger();
    private readonly Messenger eventAggregator2 = new Messenger();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.ParentViewModel1 = new ParentViewModel(this.eventAggregator1);
        this.ParentViewModel2 = new ParentViewModel(this.eventAggregator2);
    }

    public ParentViewModel ParentViewModel1 { get; }
    public ParentViewModel ParentViewModel2 { get; }
}

internal class ParentViewModel
{
    public ParentViewModel(Messenger eventAggregator)
    {
        this.ButtonsViewModel = new ButtonsViewModel(eventAggregator);
        this.ResultViewModel = new ResultViewModel(eventAggregator);
    }

    public ButtonsViewModel ButtonsViewModel { get; } 
    public ResultViewModel ResultViewModel { get; }
}

internal class ButtonsViewModel
{
    private readonly Messenger eventAggregator;

    public ButtonsViewModel(Messenger eventAggregator)
    {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

        this.StartCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.StartProcessing);
    }

    public DelegateCommand StartCommand { get; }

    private void StartProcessing()
    {
        this.eventAggregator.RaiseDoWork("test path");
    }
}

internal class ResultViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly Model model = new Model();
    private string textValue;

    public ResultViewModel(Messenger eventAggregator)
    {
        eventAggregator.DoWork += (sender, s) => this.DoWorkHandler(s);
    }

    public string TextValue
    {
        get { return this.textValue; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this.textValue, value); }
    }

    private void DoWorkHandler(string s)
    {
        var result = this.model.Process(s);
        this.TextValue = result;
    }
}
```

Note that in `ResultViewModel` I replaced `Trace.WriteLine` with actual screen output (because now strings are without Id, so trace output the same). `ViewModelBase` just implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Below demonstrated *content part* of all views "from top to bottom".

```
<!-- MainWindow.xaml -->
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <views:UserControlParent DataContext="{Binding ParentViewModel1}" />
    <views:UserControlParent DataContext="{Binding ParentViewModel2}" />
</StackPanel>

<!-- UserControlParent.xaml -->
<StackPanel>
    <local:UserControlResult DataContext="{Binding ResultViewModel}" />
    <local:UserControlButtons DataContext="{Binding ButtonsViewModel}" />
</StackPanel>

<!-- UserControlButtons.xaml -->
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Test" Command="{Binding StartCommand}" />
</Grid>

<!-- UserControlResult.xaml -->
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextValue}" />
</Grid>
```

And finally this two worlds are connected in App.xaml.cs:

```
private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    new MainWindow { DataContext = new MainViewModel() }.Show();
}
```

Seems like MVVM, but any remarks are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I would use option 1. I use MVVM Light to send a message and whoever receives that specific message will fire off the service method. Loosely coupled.

Comment: Thanks. But how would you pass Id to `UserControl1` and `UserControl3`? As I noticed in question (note about singleton), when model object in `UserControl3` receives message (wherether it Prism or MVVMLight messaging), it must ensure that message comes from view-model of particular `UserControl1`. Because I can have two groups of `UserControl`s (like in picture) in single `Window`.

Comment: @Sam you can pass a payload to the `PubSubEvent` from the `ViewModel` of `UserControl1`, and subscribe to it in `UserControl3`

Comment: @FilippoVigani Thanks, I will look at `PubSubEvent` and let you know about results.